# Rails json request from RESTful api how to render for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest

I have another rails app serving up a RESTful JSON API.   I'm able to test the response via the curl request below (you can also  see an example of the first item it returns).

I can figure out how to extract certain items from the larger response.  I'm just not sure how I should serve the response on the rails app that will render this to the client.

I'd assume I need to save this is in a class of some sort.  Can i use curl?  I'm very green with rails, and would very much apreciate any help.

THANKS!

```
curl "http://api.foobar.com/stuff/stuff_name/catalog_items.json" -H "X-Api-Key: georgesbush"
```

Which returns a nice set of JSON Data.

```
{
    "data": {
        "catalog_items": [
            {
                "current_price": "9999.0",
                "close_date": "2013-05-14T16:08:00-04:00",
                "open_date": "2013-04-24T11:00:00-04:00",
                "stuff_count": 82,
                "minimum_price": "590000.0",
                "id": 337478,
                "estimated_price": "50000.0",
                "name": "This is a really cool name",
                "current_winner_id": 696969,
                "images": [
                    {
                        "thumb_url": "http://foobar.com/images/93695/thumb.png?1365714300",
                        "detail_url": "http://foobar.com/images/93695/detail.png?1365714300",
                        "position": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "thumb_url": "http://foobar.com/images/95090/thumb.jpg?1366813823",
                        "detail_url": "http://foobar.com/images/95090/detail.jpg?1366813823",
                        "position": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "pagination": {
        "per_page": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "total_pages": 131,
        "total_objects": 131
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a framework such as Backbone, you can use this output directly and render your views on the client side.

Comment: rails on both sides unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 0):

I went with the ruby curb library, wow, too easy.  Added curb to my gem file, and the following code to my controller action:

```
http = Curl.get("http://api.foobar.com/stuff/stuff_name/catalog_items.json?per_page=1&page=1") do|http|
  http.headers['X-Api-Key'] = 'georgebush'
end
foobar =  http.body_str
@foobar = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(foobar ).symbolize_keys
```